# Undefined method `prepend' for HTTP::Client Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, httpclient, rake-task

> I am getting `undefined method prepend` error in this module while executing `call` function.
> I am not able to understand why it's giving error because in my previous rails version which was 4.2 (now 5.2) it was working perfectly fine.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `prepend' for #<HTTP::Client:0x00005564644a0560>
```

Did you mean?  present?

```
module Awr
  class Gateway
    class Error < StandardError; end

    def initialize(url:, token:)
      @url = url
      @token = token
    end

    def self.build
      self.new(
        url: ENV.fetch('AWR_API_URL'),
        token: ENV.fetch('AWR_API_TOKEN')
      )
    end

    def call(action_name,project:,**args)
      response = get_operation(action_name).execute(
        client: client,
        url: url,
        project: project,
        **make_params(args)
      )

      interpret_response(response)
    end

    def get(url)
      interpret_response(client.get(url))
    end

    def client
      HTTP.follow(max_hops: 3)
    end

    def make_params(params)
      params.merge(
        token: token
      )
    end

    private
    attr_reader :url, :token

    def interpret_response(response)
      case response.status.code
      when 200
        response
      else
        raise_response_error(response)
      end
    end

    def raise_response_error(response)
      status = response.status
      body = response.body
      raise Error.new("#{status.reason} [#{status.code}] - #{body}")
    end

    def get_operation(key)
      Operation[key]
    end

  end
end
```

module Awr

```
class Operation

  def initialize(action:,http_method:,project_key:,path:,**const_args)
    @action = action
    @http_method = http_method
    @project_key = project_key
    @path = path
    @const_args = const_args
  end

  def execute(client:,url:,project:,**params)
    client.prepend(http_method, full_url(url), 
    make_params(project,params))
  end

  def self.register(key,**args)
    raise KeyError.new("#{key} operation already defined.") if 
    lookup.has_key?(key)

    lookup[key] = new(**args)
  end

  def self.[](key)
    lookup.fetch(key)
  end

 private
   attr_reader :action,:http_method,:project_key,:path,:const_args

  def full_url(url)
    URI.join(url,path)
  end

  def make_params(project,params)
    {
      params: params.merge(
      project_key => project,
      action: action,
      **const_args
      )
    }
  end

  def self.lookup
    @lookup ||= {}
  end

  def self.reset
    @lookup = {}
  end
end
```

end

Gemfile OLD (Working)

```
http (2.0.0)
httpclient (2.8.3)
httpi (2.4.2)
```

Gemfile NEW (Not Working)

```
http (4.4.1)
httpclient (2.8.3)
httpi (2.4.4)
```

Comment: Can you share your rake task code?

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev Just added the code

Comment: The code you have provided is incomplete. How are you calling these methods? Can you provide a [mcve]? Also, your question seems to suggest that the code *used to work* with a previous version of ruby and/or rails. Is this correct? What version were you using before? Does the [mcve] (that you haven't yet provided) run on an older version? Ideally we should be able to replicate the behaviour, but currently you haven't provided sufficient information for anyone to do so, without guesswork.

Comment: @TomLord The previous ruby version was 2.3.3 and rails version was 4.2.

Comment: @Sachin You *still* haven't provided a [mcve]. From your code, I can see that `SyncProjectJob.perform_later` is being called - but you haven't shown how `SyncProjectJob` is defined, and nor have you shown the full error message. (The example is not *minimal* because there's lots of additional code un-required to replicate the problem; and it's not *complete*  because the critical code that actually triggers the error is missing.)

Comment: I presume (?) that the `HTTP::Client` being referenced in your error message is [this](https://github.com/httprb/http/blob/master/lib/http/client.rb)? But as far as I can tell, that class never seems to have implemented a `prepend` method - so I don't know how/why your code would have ever worked, or what you expect it to do.

Comment: @TomLord I have posted the particular code snippet where i am facing the error. If you can help me with this now.

Comment: @Sachin That's still not a reproducible code sample. Where is `prepend` being called? The full error message (which you haven't shown us) should say the exact file and line number. It seems to be somewhere in here: `get_operation(action_name).execute(client: client, ...)`, but I don't know what `get_operation(action_name)` returns, nor how that object is defined.

Comment: @TomLord  This is get_operation function.                                                                                            `def   get_operation(key) Operation[key]  end`   and   `get_operation(action_name) = #<Awr::Operation:0x0000563d0e7251e0 @action=:projects, @http_method=:get, @project_key=:project, @path="sync.php", @const_args={}>`     when i am executing   `get_operation(action_name).execute`  this is giving  me the error `undefined method prepend`

Comment: @TomLord  I am not calling prepend method anywhere in the project it's appearing when I call  `get_operation(action_name).execute(client: client, ...)` don't know why.

Comment: @Sachin ...And how is `Awr::Operation#execute` defined? Something in there is calling `prepend` on the `client`. That's what the error message says, but you still haven't shown the critical code nor the full error.

Comment: @TomLord I have updated the code. You were right there is a prepend method. Is it a deprecation issue because it was working perfectly well in my last rails version 4,2 but after I upgraded my project to 5.2 it's started giving this error.

Comment: OK, we finally got to the bottom of that part at least.... So you *are* calling `Http::Client#prepend`. Which I presume, but you didn't confirm, is [this file](https://github.com/httprb/http/blob/master/lib/http/client.rb). Now, like I said 5 months ago, I can't see anything about that gem having ever supported a `prepend` method - so that's very confusing... Forget the rails version and the ruby version; if this code really did use to work, then you must have updated the **gem version**. What version of the gem (as found in the `Gemfile.lock`) did you used to use?

Comment: @TomLord Yes i have updated the the gem versions due to dependencies. Please have a look.

Comment: @TomLord  I have replicated the same http, httpi and httpclient versions as it was earlier but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: @Sachin Does the old version work, or not? You wrote *"Gemfile OLD (Working)"*, and in the comment above you seem to say it *doesn't* work? Are you able to show a [mcve] of the code working, and then not working, based on a version update?

Comment: @TomLord Good news, i have change the prepend method to 'request' and it started working now. As there was no prepend method in https://github.com/httprb/http/blob/master/lib/http/client.rb so i have changed the method. Now it's working fine. New Method `client.request(http_method,full_url(url),make_params(project,params))`